# Error : [Too many arguments | SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: shell, terminal

Well i need to compare all the strings as arguments of this shell script and say if all of them are equals or not so i try this

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ejercicio_4
if [ $# -ne 6 ]
  then
        echo Número de argumentos incorrecto
  else
        if [ $1 == $2 == $3 == $4 == $5 == $6 ]

                then
                        echo Son iguales
                else
                        echo No todas las palabras son iguales
        fi
fi
```

also i try thinks like $@ == $1 but this didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're using bash, and comparing text strings, the **[[..]]** test is safer and more flexible. You can use **&&** and **||** inside them for and/or operators. So this would work :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ejercicio_4
if [ $# -ne 6 ]
then
    echo Número de argumentos incorrecto
else
    if [[ "$1" == "$2" && "$1" == "$3" && "$1" == "$4" && "$1" == "$5" && "$1" == "$6" ]]

    then
        echo Son iguales
    else
        echo No todas las palabras son iguales
    fi
fi
```

Note also that **"=="** is not actually valid syntax in the old **"["** test, although bash accepts it. You should properly only use the single-character **"="** in single-bracket tests.
If you're comparing integers, however, you should use **((..))** instead.

But I **strongly suggest you not follow this method**, since when the  number of arguments increase you will have to include a lot more conditions in the if statement which could get cumbersome. So **prefer a loop** and check the first arg with all others and see if they're equal, like given below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $# -ne 6 ]
then
    echo "Number of arguments are lesser than required number 6"
else
    number_of_elements=$#
    arguments=("$@")
    first=("$1")
    for (( i=1; i<number_of_elements; i++ )); do
        if [[ "$first" != ${arguments[i]} ]];then
            break
        fi
    done
    if [[ $i -eq $number_of_elements ]];then
        echo "All the argument strings are equal"
    else
        echo "Not equal"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Rly Thanks !! i am new on this , sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The operator for string equality usually is `=`. And such chains aren't possible either. Check your `man test`.

Normally you'd use `-a` for "and" and check for each argument individually.

```
...
if [ $1 = $2 -a $1 = $3 -a $1 = $4 -a $1 = $5 -a $1 = $6 ]; then
...
```